# MYSQL <= operator not working for values of 9999

Tags: mysql, comparison, operator-keyword

Ok guys.  I have a strange MYSQL comparison operator issue.  I have two tables, one (Table1)which contains a list of values with an upper and lower score range (MinScore, MaxScore) and a description field.  The values of the MinScore and MaxScore are stored as Int(11).

Then I have a second table (Table2) containing records to which the score is compared to the first table to join performance descriptions.

The maximum value of the Score in Table1 is 9999 (That is the highest value that can be entered).

If I have a value in Table2 of 9999 and I use a join on like the following, then I can't retrieve the values from Table1.

i.e.: .... ON (Table2.Score>=Table1.MinScore AND Table2.Score<=Table1.MaxScore)

If I change Table2.Score to 9998, it works.
If I change Table1.MaxScore to 6000 and the Table2.Score to 6000, it works.
If I change the Table1.MaxScore to 10000 and the Table2.Score to 9999 it fails.

What is it about the 9999 that causes the failure?  Any ideas?  It's not a float, nor a decimal.  Both values are INT(11) fields.

Comment: Do you have some sample data, or perhaps set up a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) that demonstrates this?

Comment: To be honest it's a gawd awfully long query joining multiple tables, so it's difficult to replicate.  It's just really weird that it works for any values below 9999 just fine, but when the values are 9999 it fails.

I will say that the Table1.Score is actually a Coalesce value like COALESCE(Score1, Score2, NULL).  But again, it's just the 9999 that's giving me grief.

Comment: The only thing I can think of without seeing the query/data is maybe someone used "9999" as a magic number?

Comment: LEFT JOIN (SELECT tmp1.sDBID, assessmentDate, assessmentType, tmp1.assessmentCode, scoreCode, rawScore, scaleScore, altScore, comment, tmp2.MaximumScore FROM studentstaarresults tmp1

Comment: INNER JOIN (SELECT sDBID, assessmentCode, MAX(COALESCE(scaleScore, altScore, NULL)) MaximumScore FROM studentstaarresults WHERE deleted=0 AND assessmentCode IN (@tests) GROUP BY sDBID, assessmentCode) tmp2 ON (tmp1.sDBID=tmp2.sDBID AND CASE WHEN NOT ISNULL(tmp1.scaleScore) THEN tmp1.scaleScore=tmp2.MaximumScore WHEN NOT ISNULL(tmp1.altScore) THEN tmp1.altScore=tmp2.MaximumScore ELSE ISNULL(tmp1.scaleScore) END) GROUP BY tmp2.sDBID, tmp2.assessmentCode) SSR ON (SSR.sDBID=SE.sDBID AND SSR.assessmentCode=AC.optValue)

Comment: LEFT JOIN (SELECT PerformanceLevel, PlanName, AssessmentCode, AssessmentVersion, StartDate, EndDate, MinScore, MaxScore FROM staarphaseinplan WHERE assessmentCode IN (@tests)) SPP ON (SPP.AssessmentCode=FD.assessmentCode AND SPP.AssessmentVersion=FD.assessmentType AND FD.FirstDate>=SPP.StartDate AND FD.FirstDate<=SPP.EndDate AND SSR.MaximumScore>=SPP.MinScore AND SSR.MaximumScore<=SPP.MaxScore)

Comment: Can you start removing parts of the query until you get the smallest possible that reproduces the problem?

Comment: That'll take some time and the Monster is wearing off.  Tomorrow I'll see what I can extract from the query to break it down a bit and see if I can isolate the offending portion.

Comment: @Max Can you post your full query as its not clear what is SSR and FD and also some sample data. Is it possible(pretty sure) that the minScore and MaxScore you are getting from SPP might not be as per your expectation because of some other conditions in the where clause.

Comment: My guess is that the coalesce expression returns strings instead of numbers, try to explicitely cast a score value to number: `CAST( COALESCE(Score1, Score2, NULL) as DECIMAL)`.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED.  Actually COALESCE was working correctly.  I had tried casting several ways.  The problem was a JOIN in the SSR subquery as @rakeshjain had supposed. (Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Your powers of mindreading are impressive!)

I had inadvertently omitted a critical ON parameter in the SSR that pulls the maximum score used to join the tables.  The ON param I missed was tmp1.assessmentCode=tmp2.assessmentCode.

Comment: @Max no upvote or answer acceptance :)

Comment: Sorry guys. Id upvote @rakeshjains response, but apparently I dont have a high enough rep yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your full query as its not clear what is SSR and FD and also some sample data. Is it possible(pretty sure) that the minScore and MaxScore you are getting from SPP might not be as per your expectation because of some other conditions in the where clause